# Use DLNA of WHS 2011

Tags: windows, media, windows-home-server, dlna

I have some media on my WHS 2011 and I want to access them with my TV. Both should support DLNA and I can see the user accounts of my server, but if I go into videos there is no file.

How can I access the files from the WHS without any third party software?

I've tried the following:

- media server is enabled
- desired folder sharing option is true (media library)
- enabled guest account
- Upnp is enabled on the router
- there is a database in C:\Users\MediaStreamingAdmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Media Player
- Guest has read access on the desired folder
- under media streaming options the TV is listed twice, but both allowed with default settings
- under advanced sharing options I have the following settings: network detection is on, file and printer sharing is on, share of the public folder is on and password protected sharing is disabled
- under homegroup settings I have enabled sharing for devices (but I haven't clicked any libraries here)

I had this working one time (nearly same setup), but I reinstalled WHS one time and now I can't get it working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why but this enabled the DLNA support for me:

> To enable HomeGroup members to access digital media
>
> 1. Open the server Dashboard
> 2. On the Dashboard Home page, click Set options for sharing.
> 3. On the Sharing Options page, click Share with Homegroup.
> 4. On the Change HomeGroup settings page, click Change settings.
> 5. For each shared folder, select the level of access that you want to
>      allow users.
> 6. Click Apply or OK to save your settings.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/gg671039(v=ws.11).aspx)